# Parsing custom URI with regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

i have a problem with regex.

i currently work on php library to create more human readable query string filter. 
([the lib](https://github.com/Symftony/Xpression), [the demo](http://symftony-xpression.herokuapp.com/index.php))

the problem come from token `value{{value}}`

regex : `/(=)\{(\S*)(\}&?|\}$)/U`

string : `queryA={valueA1{{valueA1a}}&valueA2{{valueA2a}}}&queryB={valueB1{{valueB1a}}&valueB2{{valueB2a}}}`

matches :

- `valueA1{{valueA1a` instead of `valueA1{{valueA1a}}&valueA2{{valueA2a}}`
- `valueB1{{valueB1a` instead of `valueB1{{valueB1a}}&valueB2{{valueB2a}}`

https://regex101.com/r/Dqg4SB/1

So how can i match `}$` and `}&` but NOT `}}$` and `}}&` ?

I want to match all expression between `{` and `}` without matching `{{` `}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/(=)\{([^}\s]*(?:}}[^}\s]*)*)}/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2POyo3/1).

**Details**

- `(=)` - Group 1: a `=` char
- `\{` - a `{` char
- `([^}\s]*(?:}}[^}\s]*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `[^}\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `}` and whitesapce
  - `(?:}}[^}\s]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of:

    - `}}` - a literal `}}` substring
    - `[^}\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `}` and whitesapce
- `}` - a `}` char.